# having trouble with a function to check a bitmap image

Tags: c++, c

I created a function to check whether the file opened is a bitmap or not. I wrote the following function:

```
     int auth(FILE *fp)
         {
          if (fgetc(fp)!='B' || fgetc(fp)!='M'){
                    return 0;
                    }
          else{
                 return 1;
                    }
          }
```

But this is giving an `ERROR:"FILE and fp not declared in this scope"`.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You typed `FIle`, not `FILE`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct spelling is `FILE` (all letters in upper case).

And you must `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: i already have included stdio.h and corrected the spelling mistake.
but its still giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

You must include the `<stdio.h>` header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. include `` `stdio.h ``
2. It should be in capitals FILE

Answer (score 0):

```
int auth(FILE *fp)
{
     if (fgetc(fp)!='B' || fgetc(fp)!='M') return 0;
     else return 1;
}
```

Comment: simpler: `return fgetc(fp)=='B' && fgetc(fp)=='M';`

Comment: nice, I would of thought to return 0 or 1, but the `&&` operator does that for you

Comment: just like any other boolean operator.